# Invoke sendMessage method from second activity

Tags: java, android, chromecast

I'm doing some dev for a Chromecast sender app, and I have this method in my MainActivity class:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mApiClient != null && mHelloWorldChannel != null) {
            try {
                Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(mApiClient, mHelloWorldChannel.getNamespace(), message)
                        .setResultCallback(
                                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResult(Status result) {
                                        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "Sending message failed");
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("Message sent!");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception while sending message", e);
            }
        } else {
            if (mApiClient == null) {
                System.out.println("apiClient null");
            }

            if (mHelloWorldChannel == null) {
                System.out.println("mHello null");
            }
        }
    }
```

Every works dandy and I can send messages to my Chromecast and do nifty things with them when they get there. However, I use a number of other Activities in my app, and I'd like to be able to send messages to the Chromecast from those as well.

That said, what is the best way to access this method from a second activity?

Comment: you can define that method as static.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed its a Activity class and you want to create an instance of that class. op says second activity

Comment: sorry i guess im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you will define your method static one then you can call it like this:

```
ClassName.sendMessage(String message);
```

If it is not static one, you will need to create an object for it.

```
ClassName c= new ClassName(SomeconstructorParams);
c.sendMessage(String message);
```